# Javascript beginner: setTimeout hide/show issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide an element after 2000ms by the below code.

`setTimeout($templateElement.hide(),2000);`

I am the new one to jquery and java-script. I hope Anyone clear my doubts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code

```
setTimeout($templateElement.hide(),2000);
```

***executes*** the `$templateElement.hide()` immediately and passes its return value (a jQuery object) into `setTimeout`. You may have meant:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $templateElement.hide();
}, 2000);
```

...which passes a function *reference* into `setTimeout`, to be called two seconds later. That function then does the `hide` when it gets called.

Comment: stupid question: Why doe the first function execute immediately while the second gets passed to setTimeout and executed later?

Comment: Thank you. Now i know about setTimeout method. And it was work perfectly.

Comment: @Christoph: In the code above, we *define* a function (`function() { ... }`) but we never directly call it (no `()` at the end). In the OP's code, the `()` at the end means "call the function". Suppose I have a function called `foo`. In JavaScript, `x = foo;` assigns the function reference to `x` (doesn't call it); `x = foo();` *calls* `foo` and assigns `x` its return value. The same is true when passing things into functions, `setTimeout(foo, 100)` passes a reference to `foo` into `setTimeout`; `setTimeout(foo(), 100)` calls foo immediately and passes its return value into `setTimeout`.

Comment: Can you pass $template.hide then? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Christoph: You could indeed, but it wouldn't work for an unrelated reason (within the call to `hide`, `this` would have the wrong value). Two articles on my blog expanding on that: [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) and [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html).

Comment: @Christoph: Right, using `Function#call` wouldn't work because it calls it right away (it's just another way to write `$template.hide()`). *(Edit: Looks like you deleted that comment.)* You can do it with ES5's [`Function#bind`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5) (it creates a form of closure, but without much baggage): `setTimeout($template.hide.bind($template), 2000);`. Or you can use jQuery's [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), which creates a closure closing over a different execution context: `setTimeout($.proxy($template.hide, $template), 2000);`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the enlightenment! Esp. the `$.proxy` part.